# return void 0; vs return;

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm studying the annotated source code of Underscore.js.

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-41

Here's the _.first method:

```
  _.first = _.head = _.take = function(array, n, guard) {
    if (array == null) return void 0;
    return (n == null) || guard ? array[0] : slice.call(array, 0, n);
  };
```

Question:

**Why 'return void 0;' and not just 'return;' ?** As far as I know **return** implicitly returns undefined (the value!) from a function. Just like 'return void 0' does.

Comment: it appears to be an inconsistency, as in other parts of the source `return;` is used.

Comment: Probably to make the code clearer.

Comment: it might be one of those things that can never be explained. (even if you asked the programmer who wrote it)

Comment: On [2010-12-01](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/2d06e1d5262ca2e17aa71955c7780d15acc18d5d#diff-0f36b362a0b81d6f4d4bfd8a7413c75d) the author added `return;` to the code for the first time, and `return void 0;` appeared [2012-10-06](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/a9ce927465f044cb1be22f96c2bf9752c23d15b4`). Chalk it up to the passage of two years' time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the [MDN reference for the void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) it states:

> The void operator is often used merely to obtain the undefined
>   primitive value, usually using "void(0)" (which is equivalent to "void
>   0"). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead
>   (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).

So it is indeed equivalent to `undefined` but the problem with the `undefined` variable is that it can be redefined as something else. Personally I would always simply `return;` because it consistently yields the exact same result (as in: `(function() {})() === void 0`).

### Clarification

Since some commenter consider this not an appropriate answer:

`(function() {})() === void 0` always yields true which means that it is exactly the same as `return;`. So you can consider this an inconsistency in the Underscore library as plain return statements are used in other places (yes, even there it can happen).

### Minification and optimization

Another addendum, it looks as if it also doesn't optimize any better during minification. Using the [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) the `return void 0;` vs `return;` version of the above code sample is still about 5% bigger.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that `undefined` can be reassigned? If I try `var undefined = 2` or even the naughty global `undefined = 2` and then recall `undefined`, I get ... `undefined`! Is this what you meant?

Comment: Using return without undefined, the reassignement problem can't occur. This doesn't seem to answer at all.

Comment: @guypursey The lexical identifier `undefined` can be used in a non-global scope as a variable name: `(function() { var undefined = "foo"; console.log(undefined); })()`

Comment: Here is a Fiddle of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/dXjFy/ reassigned was probably the wrong term, it should be redefined.

Comment: +1 to apsillers and Daff Was not aware of this possibility so thank you! However @dystroy is right; it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: I think it answers the question in the sense that it doesn't make a difference

Comment: As Ingo said, I think it does stating that `(function() {})() === void 0` (which is always true for any JS engine I tried). So it simply doesn't make a difference and shows that even libraries like underscore can have inconsistencies.

Comment: … and frankly I think the only "real" answer to why it was used could only come from the person writing it. We can only guess intentions, not know them. But as far as the technical side goes, Daff answered it fully. I've been reading this question and answer several times now and can't for the life of me figure out why the answer gets down-voted while an easily searchable question gets so many upvotes. Some things are just beyond me. :)

Comment: @guypursey Yes, you can change the value of the global variable **undefined** in earlier versions of ECMAScript. See the note on [mozilla's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined). It says _Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5 (Firefox 4), undefined is non-writable, as per the ECMAScript 5 specification._

Comment: @Daff Thanks! My only concern was if `(function() {})()` returns the primitive value undefined or the value of the variable `undefined` (which can be overwritten, see my previous comment). I tested that in old Firefox (which allows undefined variable to be overwritten) and got that in fact `(function() {})()` returns the primitive value.

Comment: I also asked the creators https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1315#issuecomment-26621870. So it all looks like inconsistency. A simple `return;` would do.